# How to validate some of the dynamic table cells in asp.net

Tags: frameworks

As the code below, I need to create a dynamic table in which each cell gets validated. If there is any wrong input, error message will pop up for that specific cell. Now our BA doesn’t want to display multiple error messages for each column. Only simply display one error message for each column like last name like “Last Name is invalid” no matter how many last names are invalid. How can I accomplish this? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance. I will really appreciate your response.

Thanks,
Dev2016

```
Protected Sub ShowBoxes(ByVal startRow As Integer, ByVal nRowsAdd As Integer)

    Dim d As Integer = 10
    For d = startRow To (startRow + nRowsAdd - 1)
        Dim row As New HtmlTableRow()
        row.VAlign = "center"
        row.Attributes("class") = "bgA"
        row.ID = "IndivRow_" & d.ToString
        Dim col1 As New HtmlTableCell()
        col1.Align = "center"
        col1.Width = 29
        col1.InnerHtml = (d + 1).ToString
        Dim col2 As New HtmlTableCell()
        col2.Width = 53
        col2.VAlign = "left"
        Dim txt2 As New TextBox()
        txt2.ID = "Last_" & d.ToString
        txt2.Columns = "29"
        txt2.MaxLength = "30"
        Dim reg2 As New RegularExpressionValidator()
        reg2.ID = "regLast_" & d.ToString
        reg2.ControlToValidate = "Last_" & d.ToString
        reg2.ValidationExpression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9""()-. '\s]{1,50}$"
        reg2.ErrorMessage = "Last Name on line " & (d + 1).ToString & " contains invalid characters."
        reg2.Text = "*"
        reg2.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Static
        reg2.ValidationGroup = "SubmitFormClient"
        reg2.SetFocusOnError = True
        col2.Controls.Add(txt2)
        col2.Controls.Add(reg2)
        Dim col3 As New HtmlTableCell()
        col3.Width = 53
        col3.VAlign = "left"
        Dim txt3 As New TextBox()
        txt3.ID = "First_" & d.ToString
        txt3.MaxLength = "30"
        Dim reg3 As New RegularExpressionValidator()
        reg3.ID = "regFirst_" & d.ToString
        reg3.ControlToValidate = "First_" & d.ToString
        reg3.ValidationExpression = "^[a-zA-Z0-9""()-. '\s]{1,50}$"
        reg3.ErrorMessage = "First Name on line " & (d + 1).ToString & " contains invalid characters."
        reg3.Text = "*"
        reg3.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Static
        reg3.ValidationGroup = "SubmitFormClient"
        reg3.SetFocusOnError = True
        col3.Controls.Add(txt3)
        col3.controls.add(reg3)

        row.Cells.Add(col1)
        row.Cells.Add(col2)
        row.Cells.Add(col3)
        tableIndiv.Rows.Add(row)
    Next d
End Sub
```